# Wrong tab configuration. error?

Tags: adminhtml, blocks, overrides, tabs

I am trying to extend `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_View` class in order to pass in some functions and display them using a layout update in

```
adminhtml/default/default/template/namespace/mymodule/edit/tab/view.phtml
```

I've used a rewrite in my `config.xml`

```
<blocks>
    <mymodule>
        <class>Mymodule_Customer_Block</class>
    </mymodule>
    <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
            <customer_edit_tab_view>Mymodule_Customer_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_View</customer_edit_tab_view>
        </rewrite>
    </adminhtml>
</blocks>
```

And here is the `View.php` file

```
class Mymodule_Customer_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_View extends   Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_View
{
    public function getCredit(){

        $customerId = $this->getCustomer()->getId();
        $model = Mage::registry('current_customer');
        $customerId = $model->getId();
        $data = $model->getData();

        $helper = Mage::helper('customercredit');
        $creditValue = (float)$helper->getCreditValue($customerId, $model->getWebsiteId());

        return $creditValue;
    }    
}
```

Whenever I go to view the customer edit view tab in magento admin I get an error:

> Wrong tab configuration.

I must have missed something out of my setup but I am not sure what?

Any one have any idea please let me know...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to do a little detective work.  It's very possible a different change is responsible for the error you're seeing, or that something about your replacement triggers this error.

To start, I'd remove any custom functions you have in `Mymodule_Customer_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_View` and concentrate on getting the class rewrite working without a `Wrong tab Configuration` exception — that way if the error **is** tied to a method you've added, you'll know which one when you add your methods back one by one.

The exception you're seeing comes from this method

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Tabs.php
public function addTab($tabId, $tab)
{
    if (is_array($tab)) {
        $this->_tabs[$tabId] = new Varien_Object($tab);
    }
    elseif ($tab instanceof Varien_Object) {
        $this->_tabs[$tabId] = $tab;
        if (!$this->_tabs[$tabId]->hasTabId()) {
            $this->_tabs[$tabId]->setTabId($tabId);
        }
    }
    elseif (is_string($tab)) {
        if (strpos($tab, '/')) {
            $this->_tabs[$tabId] = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($tab);
        }
        elseif ($this->getChild($tab)) {
            $this->_tabs[$tabId] = $this->getChild($tab);
        }
        else {
            $this->_tabs[$tabId] = null;
        }

        if (!($this->_tabs[$tabId] instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface)) {
            throw new Exception(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Wrong tab configuration.'));
        }
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Wrong tab configuration.'));
    }

    if (is_null($this->_tabs[$tabId]->getUrl())) {
        $this->_tabs[$tabId]->setUrl('#');
    }

    if (!$this->_tabs[$tabId]->getTitle()) {
        $this->_tabs[$tabId]->setTitle($this->_tabs[$tabId]->getLabel());
    }

    $this->_tabs[$tabId]->setId($tabId);
    $this->_tabs[$tabId]->setTabId($tabId);

    if (is_null($this->_activeTab)) $this->_activeTab = $tabId;
    if (true === $this->_tabs[$tabId]->getActive()) $this->setActiveTab($tabId);

    return $this;
}
```

And occurs when Magento can't instantiate a tab from information passed into `addTab`.  My guess is your error comes from this bit of layout XML in `catalog.xml`

```
<action method="addTab"><name>customer_edit_tab_view</name><block>customer_edit_tab_view</block></action>
```

Although adding some temporary debugging to the `addTab` method above will help with that

```
var_dump($tabId, $tab);
```

If that's the case, it sounds like Magento may be having trouble instantiating your new block class.  I'd try running the following code

```
$block = new Mymodule_Customer_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_View;
var_dump($block);

$block = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view');
var_dump($block);
```

and looking for instantiation errors (each call should return a block object).

My best guess as to why this is happening is you have your `View.php` file for `Mymodule_Customer_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_View` created in the wrong folder.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanyou @AlanStorm for your advice!

Comment: @user1704524 Out of curiosity, what was it?

Comment: `var_dump($tabId, $tab);` gives me `Fatal error: Call to a member function getUrl() on a non-object in` so the saga constinues...

Comment: Thanks for the post @AlanStorm. FYI in my case this was caused by a custom module having an XML tag which had `module="mycustom_modulename"` where the module in question didn't have a helper. That old badger.

Answer (score 1):

The approach that worked for me was to have alook at the Exception log as per the answer to this duplicate question:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/102173/12662