# Wrong tab configuration EditRoles.php

Tags: magento-1.9

I am Getting following error, when trying to create/edit user role.

```
Wrong tab configuration.

app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Editroles.php(42): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs->addTab('account', false)
```

I am unable to figure out problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have resolved this issue So, I am posting my solution here, May be it will help some one.
**Phase 1:** Debugging 
**Step 1**:Enable Log 
**Step 2**:login to your admin and try to create or edit roles.Now you will get the error message.
**Step 3**:Open exception.log file and look for Helper files error exp:

> exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: include(Mage/Missingmeta/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

**Step 4:** Comment the Module which's helper is mention in exception.log file.And repeat step 1.Now will see the problem has gone.

**Phase 2:** Solution:
**Step 5:** Make sure your helper config should be :

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <globalsms>
            <class>Php_GlobalSms_Helper</class>
        </globalsms>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

If your module has adminhtml.xml and you are using wrong configuration for menu.then it will also cause the problem.Make sure you are adding your menu in right way. You can check here [how to add menu  in admin.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45173/how-to-add-admin-page-new-menu-and-a-sub-menu-under-existing-menu)

Comment: This worked for me, it was a third party module that was ruining my day on my local dev box. Top tip: sometimes it is not your code but someone else's.

Answer (score 0):

I had had this same error, but I fix it recreating my file `adminhtml.xml`, you can use this below like a sample and changing the necessary tags, **that are line 11, 12 and 14** to your custom module name.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <YOURVENDOR_YOURMODULE>
                                        <title>YOURMODULE</title>
                                        <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                                    </YOURVENDOR_YOURMODULE>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```